# How does a connection work with embedding a website on my own website?

Tags: javascript, embed

I am making a website and I wanted to know if I embed youtube for example, will the user be connected to youtube directly, or will they be having a connection through the website which then has a connection with youtube.

If its directly to youtube, is there a way to make it connect through the website

Thanks

Comment: As it is a resource in the page that does not originate from your server the browser will open a seperate TCP connection to YouTube to load that resource into your page. But why do you want to proxy the loading of that embeded element from YouTube in the first place?

Comment: @Palladium02 In my country sites with the countries ending domain get 50% less internet usage so I thought this way people could enjoy youtube and other websites not worrying about high internet price

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.